# How can I find loading adress of eCos image

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, mips

Hey guys Im trying to find loading address (entry point of my program) for this [binary](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B95UR9turb7DWEZ1UjMyRVBXMzg/view), which is part off this [firmware](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B95UR9turb7DTXhNYm01NjVhbTg/view?usp=sharing). Im trying to load it inside of IDA, how can I correctly load it, how to find entry point address?

Here's `binwalk`'s output:

```
$ binwalk 7101C

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             eCos kernel exception handler, architecture: MIPSEL, exception vector table base address: 0x80558540
640           0x280           eCos kernel exception handler, architecture: MIPSEL, exception vector table base address: 0x80558540
4307602       0x41BA92        Unix path: /../../HB/app/tv/appTvVideo_dvb.c
4389070       0x42F8CE        Unix path: /../../HB/app/zapper/appZapper.c
4391820       0x43038C        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
4392970       0x43080A        Unix path: /../../HB/app/main/appMain.c
4393342       0x43097E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/main/appWDT.c
4393574       0x430A66        Unix path: /../../HB/app/menu/MApp_Menu.c
4393758       0x430B1E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/menu/MApp_MenuChannel.c
4397102       0x43182E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/monitor/appMonitor.c
4398262       0x431CB6        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/font/apiVectorFont.c
4398414       0x431D4E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_APIcontrols.c
4398666       0x431E4A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_APIgdi.c
4398882       0x431F22        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_APIwindow.c
4399178       0x43204A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_Main.c
4399302       0x4320C6        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/apiMvf_base.c
4399654       0x432226        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/apiMvf_grays.c
4401186       0x432822        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/database/MApp_SaveData.c
4401744       0x432A50        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
4402906       0x432EDA        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/database/apiDTVDataManager.c
4404518       0x433526        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/chscan/apiChScan.c
4405394       0x433892        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/EPG_Swap_DB/apiEPG_DB.c
4408198       0x434386        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/EPG_Swap_DB/apiEPG_EIT_Swap.c
4410158       0x434B2E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/driver/pq/drvPQ.c
4413646       0x4358CE        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/driver/pq/hal/kriti_mstar/include/QualityMap_BW.c
4414022       0x435A46        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/driver/pq/hal/kriti_mstar/mhal_pq.c
4415066       0x435E5A        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/appMM_Browser.c
4416158       0x43629E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/appPVR_playback.c
4416918       0x436596        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/MMfilesystem/apiFSUtil.c
4417234       0x4366D2        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/portinglayer/mm/src/porting_audio.c
4425946       0x4388DA        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/vdplayerV2/appMM_playback.c
4426570       0x438B4A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/MApp_ZUI_ACTglobal.c
4427538       0x438F12        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/MApp_ZUI_GDISetup.c
4427974       0x4390C6        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/widgets/MApp_ZUI_CTLsolidprogressbar.c
4428226       0x4391C2        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pagedoc/MApp_PvrZapper.c
4428446       0x43929E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pagedoc/MApp_Pvrv3.c
4438850       0x43BB42        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTAudioLanguage.c
4439082       0x43BC2A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTChannelInfo.c
4440318       0x43C0FE        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMediaMoviePlay.c
4441950       0x43C75E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMediaPlay.c
4442178       0x43C842        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMediaSimpleStart_PVR.c
4443290       0x43CC9A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMenuPvrDevice.c
4444006       0x43CF66        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTPvrSubtitleLanguage.c
4444586       0x43D1AA        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTSubtitle.c
4445218       0x43D422        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTbookmanage.c
4445966       0x43D70E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTprogedit.c
4447410       0x43DCB2        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTtvbanner.c
4448530       0x43E112        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTtvfavoritelist.c
4448774       0x43E206        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_Utility.c
5003844       0x4C5A44        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/s
5003845       0x4C5A45        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/sm"
5003875       0x4C5A63        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/smp.hxx"
5003893       0x4C5A75        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/smp.hxx"
5003981       0x4C5ACD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/"
5004011       0x4C5AEB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mempolt2.inl"
5004029       0x4C5AFD        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mempolt2.inl"
5004125       0x4C5B5D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/malloc.cxx"
5004155       0x4C5B7B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/malloc.cxx"
5004221       0x4C5BBD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/misc.cxx"
5004251       0x4C5BDB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/misc.cxx"
5004333       0x4C5C2D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_supp.c"
5004363       0x4C5C4B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_supp.c"
5005580       0x4C610C        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_ncache.c
5005581       0x4C610D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_ncache.c"
5005611       0x4C612B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_ncache.c"
5005940       0x4C6274        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_blib.c
5005941       0x4C6275        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_blib.c"
5005971       0x4C6293        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_blib.c"
5006676       0x4C6554        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/disk/v2_0_60/src/disk.c
5006677       0x4C6555        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/disk/v2_0_60/src/disk.c"
5006707       0x4C6573        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/disk/v2_0_60/src/disk.c"
5008348       0x4C6BDC        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/hal/common/v2_0_60/src/hal_misc.c
5008349       0x4C6BDD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/hal/common/v2_0_60/src/hal_misc.c"
5008379       0x4C6BFB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/hal/common/v2_0_60/src/hal_misc.c"
5008609       0x4C6CE1        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos][CPU INFO] : CPU Clock = %d : RTC Period = %d"
5009060       0x4C6EA4        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/clock.cxx
5009061       0x4C6EA5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/clock.cxx"
5009091       0x4C6EC3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/clock.cxx"
5009409       0x4C7001        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/kapi.cxx"
5009439       0x4C701F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/kapi.cxx"
5009493       0x4C7055        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/th"
5009523       0x4C7073        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/thread.inl"
5009541       0x4C7085        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/thread.inl"
5010176       0x4C7300        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/thread.cxx
5010177       0x4C7301        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/thread.cxx"
5010207       0x4C731F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/thread.cxx"
5010465       0x4C7421        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/except.cxx"
5010495       0x4C743F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/except.cxx"
5010684       0x4C74FC        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/intr/intr.cxx
5010685       0x4C74FD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/intr/intr.cxx"
5010715       0x4C751B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/intr/intr.cxx"
5011337       0x4C7789        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/mlqueue.cxx"
5011367       0x4C77A7        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/mlqueue.cxx"
5011925       0x4C79D5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/sched.cxx"
5011955       0x4C79F3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/sched.cxx"
5012620       0x4C7C8C        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/cnt_sem.cxx
5012621       0x4C7C8D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/cnt_sem.cxx"
5012651       0x4C7CAB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/cnt_sem.cxx"
5012833       0x4C7D61        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/flag.cxx"
5012863       0x4C7D7F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/flag.cxx"
5013293       0x4C7F2D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/mb"
5013323       0x4C7F4B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/mboxt2.inl"
5013341       0x4C7F5D        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/mboxt2.inl"
5014181       0x4C82A5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/mutex.cxx"
5014211       0x4C82C3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/mutex.cxx"
5014897       0x4C8571        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/dlmalloc.cxx"
5014927       0x4C858F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/dlmalloc.cxx"
5015649       0x4C8861        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/setjmp/v2_0_60/src/longjmp.cxx"
5015679       0x4C887F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/setjmp/v2_0_60/src/longjmp.cxx"
5015829       0x4C8915        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdi"
5015859       0x4C8933        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stream.inl"
5015877       0x4C8945        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stream.inl"
5016101       0x4C8A25        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/stream.cxx"
5016131       0x4C8A43        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/stream.cxx"
5016201       0x4C8A89        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdi"
5016231       0x4C8AA7        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/streambuf.inl"
5016249       0x4C8AB9        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/streambuf.inl"
5017624       0x4C9018        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/string/v2_0_60/src/strtok.cxx
5017625       0x4C9019        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/string/v2_0_60/src/strtok.cxx"
5017655       0x4C9037        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/string/v2_0_60/src/strtok.cxx"
5018041       0x4C91B9        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/fd.cxx"
5018071       0x4C91D7        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/fd.cxx"
5018177       0x4C9241        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/file.cxx"
5018207       0x4C925F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/file.cxx"
5018605       0x4C93ED        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/dir.cxx"
5018635       0x4C940B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/dir.cxx"
5018749       0x4C947D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/select.cxx"
5018779       0x4C949B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/select.cxx"
5018857       0x4C94E9        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/main.cxx"
5018887       0x4C9507        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/main.cxx"
5019141       0x4C9605        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdi"
5019171       0x4C9623        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stdiofiles.inl"
5019189       0x4C9635        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stdiofiles.inl"
5020472       0x4C9B38        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/_exit.cxx
5020473       0x4C9B39        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/_exit.cxx"
5020503       0x4C9B57        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/_exit.cxx"
5020609       0x4C9BC1        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/atexit.cxx"
5020639       0x4C9BDF        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/atexit.cxx"
5021120       0x4C9DC0        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/attrib.c
5021121       0x4C9DC1        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/attrib.c"
5021151       0x4C9DDF        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/attrib.c"
5021876       0x4CA0B4        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/ntfs_blib.c
5021877       0x4CA0B5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/ntfs_blib.c"
5021907       0x4CA0D3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/ntfs_blib.c"
5033632       0x4CCEA0        Unix path: /home/mstar/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/audio/halAUDIO.c
5033707       0x4CCEEB        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/audio/halAUDIO.c"
5038144       0x4CE040        Unix path: /home/stb/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/dac/halDAC.c
5038217       0x4CE089        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/dac/halDAC.c"
5066028       0x4D4D2C        Unix path: /home/mstar/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/mvd/halMVD.c
5066103       0x4D4D77        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/mvd/halMVD.c"
5091476       0x4DB094        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos Newhost"
5108812       0x4DF44C        Unix path: /home/stb/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/ve/mhal_tvencoder.c
5108885       0x4DF495        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/ve/mhal_tvencoder.c"
5109464       0x4DF6D8        Unix path: /home/franke.wu/workspace/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/msos/ecos/MsOS_ecos.c
5109544       0x4DF728        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/msos/ecos/MsOS_ecos.c"
5109566       0x4DF73E        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/MsOS_ecos.c"
5109576       0x4DF748        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos.c"
5110012       0x4DF8FC        Unix path: /home/franke.wu/workspace/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/drv/miu/drvMIU.c
5110092       0x4DF94C        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/drv/miu/drvMIU.c"
5110300       0x4DFA1C        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/drv/sys/drvDMD_VD_MBX.c"
5304106       0x50EF2A        Unix path: /../src/si_v2/apiSI.c
5307730       0x50FD52        Unix path: /../src/dvb_subtitle/apiSubtitle_DC2_Decoder.c
5308386       0x50FFE2        Unix path: /../src/dvb_subtitle/apiSubtitle_Decoder.c
5403172       0x527224        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
5407268       0x528224        CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
5428390       0x52D4A6        Unix path: /../src/mm/mapp_music.c
5431970       0x52E2A2        Unix path: /../src/espvr/apiEsPVR.cpp
5433930       0x52EA4A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/api/mapi_pvr_browser.cpp
5434774       0x52ED96        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/api/mapi_pvr.cpp
5438298       0x52FB5A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/utility/PVR_File_Operand.cpp
5438798       0x52FD4E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_File_Root.cpp
5439894       0x530196        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_Metadata.cpp
5441758       0x5308DE        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_Download.cpp
5443490       0x530FA2        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_DualDownload.cpp
5445230       0x53166E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_ESPlayer.cpp
5445914       0x53191A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_Manager.cpp
5447010       0x531D62        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_TSPlayer.cpp
5448770       0x532442        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_Splitted_File.cpp
5449582       0x53276E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_Sys.cpp
5450354       0x532A72        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Thread.cpp
5452094       0x53313E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Upload_State_Scan.cpp
5452634       0x53335A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_VideoParser.cpp
5453802       0x5337EA        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/data_manager/PVR_Data_RingBuffer.cpp
5454258       0x5339B2        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_File_IO_Read.cpp
5456690       0x534332        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_File_IO_Write.cpp
5457670       0x534706        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Upload_State_188Normal.cpp
5458488       0x534A38        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/infra/v2_0_60/src/pure.cxx
5458489       0x534A39        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/infra/v2_0_60/src/pure.cxx"
5458519       0x534A57        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/infra/v2_0_60/src/pure.cxx"
5458613       0x534AB5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/kapi.cxx"
5458643       0x534AD3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/kapi.cxx"
5460693       0x5352D5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/"
5460723       0x5352F3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mfiximpl.inl"
5460741       0x535305        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mfiximpl.inl"
5461473       0x5355E1        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/"
5461503       0x5355FF        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mvarimpl.inl"
5461521       0x535611        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mvarimpl.inl"
5462269       0x5358FD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/setvbuf.cxx"
5462299       0x53591B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/setvbuf.cxx"
5522696       0x544508        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/i18n/v2_0_60/src/locale.cxx
5522697       0x544509        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/i18n/v2_0_60/src/locale.cxx"
5522727       0x544527        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/i18n/v2_0_60/src/locale.cxx"
5523265       0x544741        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/input/fgetc.cxx"
5523295       0x54475F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/input/fgetc.cxx"
5524333       0x544B6D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/time/v2_0_60/src/strftime.cxx"
5524363       0x544B8B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/time/v2_0_60/src/strftime.cxx"
6055568       0x5C6690        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5A, dictionary size: 4194304 bytes, uncompressed size: 16384 bytes
7114983       0x6C90E7        Boot section Start 0x7040000 End 0x-FFF9
7564060       0x736B1C        YAFFS filesystem
```

Here is [boot log](http://pastebin.com/uT5X3y7t)

Comment: the "binary" you linked is just a text script  with uboot commands

Comment: Thank you for investigating binary and helping out but I also find this
    binwalk -Y 7101C
    DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
840           0x348           MIPS executable code, 32/64-bit, little endian, at least 1250 valid instructions

Comment: The 7101C  has MIPS code, yes, but *not* the `usb_backup_upgrade.bin` in the first link.

Comment: Yes usb_backup_upgrade.bin contain boot loader and firmware 7101C is part of usb_backup_upgrade.bin